# Signing and only signing SOAP body with Transport layer security in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to sign a SOAP message in an IIS server with C# using X509 Certificates.  I also plan to use transport layer security and doing SOAP encryption, as well, is overkill for my needs.  I want to just sign the message body, a time stamp and a few other elements.

From looking into the configurations, it appears that there is no way to "only" sign a SOAP message, if you get into WS-Security, you end up stuck with both signing and encrypting and the only options available revolve around what you'd like to cover and what order to do the security operations with...

Is that true?  Is there some other way to do this that I am missing???

Comment: IIS has nothing to do with SOAP. Your web services stack has to deal with the signing.

Comment: OK... We're working in C# hosted on IIS - can you point me to documentation of what the options might be in terms of different stacks?  It had seemed to me from the documentation that IIS did the heavy lifting... please point me to documentation that gives me other options.

Comment: IIS does almost  nothing. WCF is doing all the work.

Comment: OK... is there any other option besides WCF?

Comment: Not really. Why would there be one? This is what WCF is designed for.

Comment: The way you wrote the first comment led me to believe that's what you were implying... given that there are multiple implementations for web services on JEE servers, I assumed that's what you were trying to say with the original comment.

Comment: The analogy is not exact. IIS is not the application server - it's the hosting environment. It's not the equivalent of J2EE.

Answer (score 1):

This is feasible in the context of a WCF message contract. Link has the the relevant enumeration. If you're not using WCF, this might still provide you a pointer to the relevant WS- information you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractmemberattribute.protectionlevel.aspx